# Postman pre-request script: Can't access header from response

Tags: javascript, postman-pre-request-script

I am writing the following pre-request Script to get my JWT for authentication:

```js
pm.sendRequest(echoPostRequest, function (err, res) {
    console.log(err, res, typeof res);
    if(err === null){
        console.log(res.header)
        // var authHeader = res.header.find(v => {v.key === 'Authorization'})
    }
});
```

This is what the console output currently looks like:

```
null, {id: "4ba2b741-316e-454d-b896-eab3aef74ae2", status: "OK", code: 200…}, object
undefined 
OK

// If you enlarge the opbject it looks like the following:

id: "4ba2b741-316e-454d-b896-eab3aef74ae2"
status: "OK"
code: 200
header: [10] <--- There are my headers ?!
stream: {…}
cookie: [0]
responseTime: 121
responseSize: 0
```

The problem is I can not access the `header` array the script always tells me it is `undefined`, same if I try the access the `cookie` array. But I can access every other single property, maybe it's because `header` and `cookie` are arrays? I don't know. Any ideas what I am doing wrong and how I can get my `Authorization` header?

Answer (score 2):

I think the Problem must be a bug, my workaround is to stringify and parse the object as json, than the headers are accessible.

```
r = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `res.headers.get('keyName')` instead.

Response object from `pm.sendRequest()` has a `headers` member of type `HeaderList`. The `HeaderList` offer a `get(key)` method to acquire the header value by key.

See [postman documentation](https://www.postmanlabs.com/postman-collection/Response.html#headers) for more details.